# onPlaybackRateChanged works in iOS but not android (react-native-video)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

I'm wondering if anybody has found a workaround or a solution for this. I see issues in the repo that don't show anything, and I *really* would rather just have the hook call on android as well. Has anybody figured out how to make it work? Even the examples don't work. It's nothing complicated. The exposed method does not call on android `(e.g. onPlaybackRateChanged={() => console.log('changed')}`

The issue goes back well before react-native-video 4.4.x and I'm using the current version.
RN .60+ (.68)

Comment: I remember having this issue. Have you tried the solution suggested here: https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2478

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that one, but it fixed it (at least it seems). Thanks!